# Отступы в не фиксированном по ширине блоке

Tags: html, css, responsive

1. Если у меня ширина сайта, к примеру, 100%. На макете в psd естественно все фиксировано (но должно растягиваться) и ширина на макете 1000px в десктопе и 500рх в таблет, а отступ в логотипе 100рх и 20рх с лева соответственно. Как мне сделать 100рх и 20рх отступ или 10% и 4%?
2. Поскольку ширина не фиксирована то центрально спозиционнировать margin: 0 auto; я не могу, я делаю display: inline; для блока, а содержимое позиционирую text-align:center;  это нормальный прием или нужно как то по другому?

Comment: скрин макета покажите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Попробуй оба варианта и посмотри, как лучше смотрится при изменении размера.
2. Перемудрил, обычный `display:block` без ширины даст 100% минус margin.

Comment: Спасибо. 2-й вариант прокатил!